# Convert String into Date with its actual Date Format

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have a text file which have field Date_. it contain date format like that
20150730 and now i want to convert it into this format 2015-07-30 in Modifed Java Script Step. and then store into PostgreSQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving dates as string with the same format you can do this.

```
var date= "20150730";

var outputDate = [date.slice(0, 4), "-", date.slice(4)].join('');
outputDate = [outputDate.slice(0, 7), "-", outputDate.slice(7)].join('');

alert(outputDate);
```

Look my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oo9bc80k/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Look at javascript `slice` function, which returns substrings spliced by indexes, and `join` function wich concate an array to string.

Comment: Thanks..
And If i Want to convert this string into date in Modified Java Script step in pentaho then is it Right
new_date=str2date("outputDate","yyyy-MM-DD");

Comment: if you want to convert this string into date is so easy. You only have to do this `new Date(outputdate);` beacuse `YYYY-MM-DD` is ISO format.

Comment: but when i use new Date function it change the Date Format in my final output(PostgreSQL).
Although I was change the data type in postgreSQL but i want to do this in JavaScript step.

Comment: Of course, when you parse string into date it change its format. I think you can pass the date as string to postgress